# Adding index on joined tables SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, indexing, join

Is it possible to add an index to select statements with joined tables? If it's possible to add an index to select statements similar to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
    V.colA, VE.colB 
FROM 
    tbl1 V 
JOIN 
    tbl2 VE ON V.colAB = VE.colAB
WHERE 
    VE.colBC = '1' AND V.colUser = 'userId'
```

I want it to create an index that gets the columns `VE.colBC` and `V.colUser` using SQL Server Management Studio. I do not know how to put it into the query. I tried this but apparently it is incorrect:

```
CREATE INDEX indexTest ON tbl1 (colUser, colBC)
```

So how can I make it work?

Comment: You cannot create an index with columns from two separate tables; an index is always **on a single** table

Comment: I see, I just looked into @Tcks answer about indexed views.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think if you create an index on tbl1.colUser and another index on tbl2 (VE) on (tbl2.colAB, tbl2.colBC) and move the VE.colBC predicate to the join clause like: ON V.colAB = VE.colAB AND VE.colBC = '1' WHERE V.colUser = 'userId' you will have more or less the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can not add index on select statement, but you can create [Indexed View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx).